# Oracle Sql Developer DataModeler not showing ERD in relational model

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Sql Developer Datamodeler to view table relationships as an ERD.

I have selected tables from the schema that are related and have common keys. Still Oracle Sql Developer Datamodeler does not show how the tables are related. Why?

[image: Relational Model. No relation between Pk-Fk shown]

Comment: Do you have HR schema? Have you tried following these steps [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-may/o34sqldev-2193423.html). It works for me

Comment: Did you define foreign keys?

Comment: These tables don't have a PK-FK assigned to them. Assigning them the keys solves the issue.

Comment: I've found this tool really flakey, and it takes patience plus synchronisation options to do this, presuming your keys exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspecting that there is no foreign key relation in your table design.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your relationships correct and still not showing the relationships, please disconnect and connect back the db connections in SQL Developer. You will be able to see the relationships properly